# Saving set of image as a cell array of image names

Tags: matlab

my problem is to retrieve a set of 100 images and save them to a cell array using `for` loop so that my cell array looks just like as would look for command below-

`imageNames = {'1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', .. . . . . ,'100.jpg'}`

Cell array contains name of each image.

Comment: Sorry I'm afraid I didn't understood fully. What you want to save in the cell array, the names or the images itself?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: "name of the images" isn't a question. You have just described a problem, but at no point have you indicated what part you want help with. Do you want to know how to generate a list of strings like `{'1.jpg', '2.jpg'...`?

Comment: in my question, `imageNames` will create a cell array of image names, i want to do it with a `for` loop

Comment: @user3416063 That was pretty confusing indeed. Make sure to use proper examples.

Comment: @user3416063 Check out **Edit 1** in my answer for an alternate solution using `ls`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear. What does retrieve exactly mean?

I assume you have 100 files in a folder and want to create a cell array with the file names.
The `dir` command should come in handy, then followed by an `arrayfun` to convert the array of structs including the names to a cell array of names only.

```
files = dir('*.jpg');
names_in_cell_array = arrayfun(@(x) x.name, files, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you were looking to create a cell array of strings `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `3.jpg`, etc., use this -

```
cellfun(@strtrim,cellstr(strcat(num2str([1:100]'),'.jpg'))','uni',0)
```

Output -

```
'1.jpg'    '2.jpg'    '3.jpg'    '4.jpg'    '5.jpg'    '6.jpg'    '7.jpg'  ....
```

**Edit 1:** If you were looking to get the `JPG` filenames into a cell array, you may use [**`ls`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/ls.html) to list out all JPG filenames and then store into a cell array like this -

```
regexp(ls('*.jpg'),'\s ','Split')
```

Comment: can you change the code to have access of file names through directory instead of just saving *.jpg to cell

Comment: Post an example of what you intend to achieve?

Comment: Sir, I have obtained the desired result. But as you asked i make my question more clear. I have a folder that contains 100 images. I want to access image names from directory to create cell array.

Comment: Which could be done with either of the answers posted here right?